# hibernate setMaxResults & setFetchSize performance issue

Tags: hibernate

Getting some performance issue with below hibernate query as the `pageSize` increases

```
ctriteria
  .setFirstResult(pageSize * pageNumber)
  .setMaxResults(pageSize)
  .setFetchSize(pageSize)
  .list();
```

I have 400k records and need to fetch 300 in each iteration, so as iterations go high query taking more time to give results.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Query is giving performance issue, so is there any way to achieve it by modifying the above query? or if any one already went through this issue and resolved some how?